# Highlight the background of an equation in Beamer using package Tikz

Tags: beamer, syntax-highlighting, hf-tikz

[image]Hi would like to simply highlight a part of a formula using the package tikZ but I am facing some difficulties in doing so.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{framed,multirow}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{dsfont} 
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{graphicx, changepage, mathtools, array}
\usepackage{color,xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}
\usepackage[beamer,customcolors]{hf-tikz}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{eqnarray}
E[\textbf{Y}] &=& m\bm{\pi} \label{eq: ExpDM}   \\
Var[\bm{Y}] &=& m\tikzmarkin{right delim frac 2}\{1+\rho^2(m-1)\}\tikzmarkend{right delim frac 2}\{diag(\bm{\pi})-\bm{\pi}\bm{\pi}'\} \label{eq: VarDM}
\end{eqnarray}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

In particular I don't get anything highlighted

Comment: Please, can you provide a sketch, what you like to have. Your document examples contain errors and can't be compiled.

Comment: I edited it and now there is an example

Comment: your code still throw error: `LaTeX cmd Error: Missing required argument for command '\tikzmarkin'`. Also it is still not complete (missed is `\nd{documennt}`. Please check your code again.

Comment: I know that there is an error, this is why I am writing here.. I would like to solve it and I am asking for help

Comment: BTW, in your preamble you load some packages twice or even more. Please, clean up it an insert only to your problem relevant pckages.

Comment: When I tried an example from the manual, it threw the same error. Maybe this package is not up-to-date and has now conflict with the newest version of `tikzmark` on which it was built. I definitely would use `tikzmark` package, since it's still maintained and works well.

Comment: I think with the recent version of `xparse` require that in presentation mode one really needs to include the overlay specification, i.e., `\tikzmarkin<1>{right delim frac 2}\{1+\rho^2(m-1)\}\tikzmarkend{right delim frac 2}`.

Answer (score 4):

By use of the `tcolorbox` package:

[image]

- It is not entirely clear, what is your problem.
- Showed image has nothing common with provided document example.
- In MWE below, which reproduce above image, are removed all duplicated and to problem irrelevant packages. You should be aware, that `beamer` load some packages as `amsmath`, `graphicx` and `xcolor`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, theorems}
\tcbset{fonttitle=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile] 
\frametitle{Code of the emphasised equation}

    \begin{itemize}
\item   Esempio:
    \[
\tcboxmath[colback=teal!25!white,
           colframe=teal]{ x + y = 10}
    \]
\item   Codice:

\begin{verbatim}
    \[\tikzmarkin<2->{a} x+
      \tikzmarkin<1>{b}y\tikzmarkend{b}
      =\tikzmark{a}\]
\end{verbatim}

    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
Emphasized equation in above MWE has different code as it is written in MWE. Verbatim in frame, containing it, is:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins, theorems}
\tcbset{fonttitle=\footnotesize}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile] % fragile is needed due to use verbatim in frame
\frametitle{Reproduction of the showed frame image}

    \begin{itemize}
\item   Esempio:
\[
\tcboxmath[colback=teal!25!white,
           colframe=teal]{x + y = 10}
\]
\item   Codice:

\begin{verbatim}
\[
\tcboxmath[colback=teal!25!white,
           colframe=teal]{ x + y = 10}
\]
\end{verbatim}

    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (1):**

In the cases, when you like to have emphasized only part of equation, then try the following solution:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\tcbset{boxrule=0.6pt,
        boxsep=4pt, 
        left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
        colframe=teal,colback=teal!25!white,
        highlight math style={enhanced},
        }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile] 
\frametitle{Use \texttt{tcolorbox} inside math expressions}

    \begin{itemize}
\item   Esempio:
    \[
\tcbhighmath{x + y} = 10
    \]
\item   Codice:

        \alert{In preamble}:
\begin{verbatim}
\tcbset{boxrule=0.6pt,
        boxsep=4pt,
        left=0pt,right=0pt,top=0pt,bottom=0pt,
        colframe=teal,colback=teal!25!white,
        highlight math style={enhanced},
        }
\end{verbatim}

    \alert{In frame body}:
\begin{verbatim}
    \[
\tcbhighmath{x + y} = 10
    \]
\end{verbatim}

    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Addendum (2):**
With use of `tikzmark` library:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fit, 
                tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Use \texttt{tikzmarknode} inside math expressions}

    \begin{itemize}
\item   Esempio:
    \[
\tikzmarknode{A}{x + y} = 10
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
    F/.style = {draw=red, rounded corners, fill=red!30,
                inner xsep=1pt, fit=#1,
                fill opacity=0.25, text opacity=1}
                    ]
\node [F=(A)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\item   Codice:

\footnotesize
\begin{verbatim}
    \[
\tikzmarknode{A}{x + y} = 10
%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay, remember picture,
    F/.style = {draw=red, rounded corners, fill=red!30,
                inner xsep=1pt, fit=#1,
                fill opacity=0.25, text opacity=1}
                    ]
\node [F=(A)] {};
\end{tikzpicture}
    \]
\end{verbatim}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]